# Who made the cover art for this album?

Tags: artwork

I'm trying to find out who made cover art for the album "The Inventors Vol. 1" by "The Arcs". I can't find it anywhere :(

Thanks in advance.

[image: cover of the album The Inventors Vol. 1]

Comment: Maybe Nonesuch records could answer that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by a guy called Omar Juarez, known as "El Oms". I found the credits on The Arcs' webpage for the album here:

http://www.thearcs.com/news/record-store-day-arcs-vs-inventors-vol-i-21036

Here's a link to the artist's Instagram account! Some funky stuff on there:

https://www.instagram.com/el_oms_/

Hope this helps xxx